# I want to re-render a specific component in ReactNative when receiving data on mqtt socket

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm writing an app with ReactNative to display heatmap-graph whenever receiving data on Mqtt socket protocol.

My problem is that I don't know how to re-render just one specific Heatmap component whenever I receive data on mqtt Socket.

If I use `useState(data)` when I receive data, in return function { } a lot of components will be re-rendering. Performance will be poor.

```js
function RenderingPage() {

    // if I use this way, a lot of components will be re-rendering 
    // whenever receiving socket data 

    // const [data, setData] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        mqttConnect();
    }, []);

    function mqttConnect() {
        //skip connect process..
        client.on('message', function (topic, data) {
        // it's my data to display. 
        // setData(data)
    }

    return(
    <SafeAreaView>
        ... a lot of components ...

       // I have to pass data to this component for drawing Heatmap
       <HeatMap
         data={data}
      />

    </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem on my way.
i think here is just one solution. That's to start MqttConnect() in  component. If i wanna use the value receiving from MqttConnect, I found I have to use module for state management such as context or Redux..

So, I put the mqtt connection function to Heatmap component.

```
export default function HeatMap() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // when mount, run once.
    let client = mqttConnect();

  return () => {
  //when unmount, quit mqtt.
  client.end();
  };
 });
}
```